# Need to open SVG files in a program but they default to IE

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I want to change the default *open with* from Internet Explorer to a program that I use (Silhouette Studio).  I have gone into the default app settings and I can see other file types that open with silhouette, but SVGs are associated with Internet Explorer with no option to change it. How do I change the setting?

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

In Default Apps, click on "Choose default apps by file type", scroll down to ".svg", and choose Silhouette Studio.

## Option 2

In Default Apps, click on "Set defaults by app", scroll down to your program, click on either Internet Explorer or Silhouette Studio, find SVG, and then change the app to your desired app.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been searching for this for ages and even MIcrosoft support wasn't helpful.  I had tried the first way but it didn't work - but the second option did it!  Thanks again